# ¿Cómo obtener todos los valores del select al hacer onchange?

Tags: jquery

Necesito obtener todos los valores del `select` al hacer `onchange` en jQuery, no solamente el que se selecciono, ¿alguna idea?.

Si fuera en jqGrid, sería genial.

Answer (score 3):

Pienso que es posible como:

```js
function printOptions()
{
 $("#cars option").each(function()
  {
   console.log($(this).attr('value'));
  });
}

$("#cars").change(function() {
 printOptions();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <select id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Yo pienso que es posible como

Comment: Hola, no es necesario usar jsfiddle, puedes usar snippets en tu respuesta presionando `Ctrl`+`M`

Comment: Ah gracias! :-)

Comment: De nada amigo :)